# SQL server erro a criar tabela

Tags: sql, servidor, table

Tentei criar varias tabelas no SQL mas 2 delas deram o mesmo erro:

> "Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 72
>   Foreign key 'FK__movimento__codem__3118447E' references invalid table "emprestimo".

E

> "Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 72.Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors."

Essas são as duas tabelas:

```
create table emprestimo(
    codemprestimo smallint,
    dataemprestimo varchar(10),
    valoremprestimo float,
    taxajuro float,
    numeroemprestimo smallint,
    observacoes varchar(100),
    codagencia smallint,
        foreign key(codagencia) references agencia(codagencia)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade,
        codconta smallint,
        foreign key(codconta) references conta(codconta)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade,
        primary key(codemprestimo));

create table movimentoconta(
codmovconta smallint,
datamov varchar(10),
valormov float,
codtipomov smallint,
    foreign key(codtipomov) references tipomovimento(codtipomov)
    on update cascade
    on delete cascade,
    codemprestimo smallint,
    foreign key (codemprestimo) references emprestimo(codemprestimo)
    on update cascade
    on delete cascade,
    codclienteconta smallint,
    foreign key(codclienteconta) references clienteconta(codclienteconta)
    on update cascade
    on delete cascade,
    primary key(codmovconta));
```

Comment: 1. A tabela `agencia` já existe? O campo `codagencia` a tabela `agencia`, é `primary key`? 2. Precisa criar o campo `codemprestimo`, na tabela `movimentoconta` para que o mesmo seja referenciado, e ainda `primary key`. Isso tudo se realmente deseja colocar as `foreign key`

Comment: a tabela tipomovimento existe ? Qual a PK dela ? Não conheço a síintexe mas faça também colunas e indices de forma separada

Answer (score 2):

Para que as FKs funcione no create é necessário que a tabela referenciada exista, que o campo referenciado exista e que esse campo seja PK (chave primaria). Com base no seu create montei um script que irá te auxiliar um pouco e identificar qual dessas não é pk, se não exista na tabela ou até se a tabela existe. Caso o campo não seja PK, você terá que alterar o seu script de create e utilizar um campo que seja PK.
 Espero ter ajudado.

```
    Declare @Parametros as table(id int identity(1,1),tabela varchar(100),campo varchar(100))
    Declare @tabela varchar(100)
    Declare @campo varchar(100)
    Declare @id int
    Declare @ok int

/* seus campos conforme o create */

    insert into @Parametros
    Values('agencia','codagencia'),
          ('conta','codconta'),
          ('tipomovimento','codtipomov'),
          ('emprestimo','codemprestimo'),
          ('clienteconta','codclienteconta')

    SELECT @ok = count(*) from @Parametros

    Declare @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    create table emprestimo(
        codemprestimo smallint,
        dataemprestimo varchar(10),
        valoremprestimo float,
        taxajuro float,
        numeroemprestimo smallint,
        observacoes varchar(100),
        codagencia smallint,
            foreign key(codagencia) references agencia(codagencia)
            on update cascade
            on delete cascade,
            codconta smallint,
            foreign key(codconta) references conta(codconta)
            on update cascade
            on delete cascade,
            primary key(codemprestimo));
    GO
    create table movimentoconta(
    codmovconta smallint,
    datamov varchar(10),
    valormov float,
    codtipomov smallint,
        foreign key(codtipomov) references tipomovimento(codtipomov)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade,
        codemprestimo smallint,
        foreign key (codemprestimo) references emprestimo(codemprestimo)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade,
        codclienteconta smallint,
        foreign key(codclienteconta) references clienteconta(codclienteconta)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade,
        primary key(codmovconta));'



    while exists (select top 1 1 from @Parametros)
    begin

    select top 1
            @id = id 
          , @tabela = tabela
          , @campo = campo           
      from @Parametros

    if exists (select top 1 1 from sys.tables where name = @tabela )
    BEGIN
    if exists (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.sysobjects AS T (NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS C (NOLOCK) ON T.id = C.object_id AND T.XTYPE = 'U' 
                    WHERE T.NAME = @tabela AND C.NAME = @campo )
    BEGIN
    if exists (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tabela 
                  AND COLUMN_NAME = @campo
                  AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo' )
    BEGIN
    set @ok = @ok - 1
    if @ok <= 0
    begin
    SELECT 'Create OK, rode o script ==> ', @SQL as Script
    end
    END ELSE BEGIN select ('CAMPO INFORMADO ' + @campo + ' NÃO É PK') break; END
    END ELSE BEGIN select ('CAMPO '+ @campo +' NÃO EXISTE NA TABELA') break; END
    END ELSE BEGIN select ('TABELA '+ @tabela +' NÃO EXISTE')         break; END

     delete from @Parametros where id = @id 

    end
```